# Using Perl's DBI, how can join the results of fetchrow_arrayref?

Tags: perl, dbi

I am new to Perl, and I am writing a script to fetch some rows from a database:

```
my @rows = $conn->fetchrow_array(1,2,3);
```

the result will be three rows of single column.

```
12345
56789
12376
```

How should I join them together as `12345,56789,56789`

I tried,

```
my $list = join ",", @rows.
```

Result: `ARRAY(0x14f6de0),ARRAY(0x1508a90),ARRAY(0x15014c0)`

Going through a `foreach` loop just print the results with a new line:

```
12345
56789
12376
```

What am I doing wrong ? have I got the concept of `fetchrow_array` wrong?

Comment: A quick update, I tried pushing them to a new_array with in the foreach loop and join them again outside the foreach loop. That seem to work. But I would be interested in knowing other ways that s beter and efficient. Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Each row is a reference to an array (because each row could contain multiple columns). Something like the following should work.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict; use warnings;

my @rows = (
    [ 12345 ],
    [ 56789 ],
    [ 12376 ],
);

my @vals = map @$_, @rows;

print join(',', @vals), "\n";
```

However, you are better off using [`selectcol_arrayref`](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/DBI#selectcol_arrayref):

> This utility method combines "prepare", "execute", and fetching one column from all the rows, into a single call. It returns a reference to an array containing the values of the first column from each row.

Comment: I tred and it works Great ! But sorry for being so naive, I did not understand how it works. What's the difference between pushing and map ?

Comment: With the `map @$_`, you are dereferencing each row reference in `@rows` which gives you, for every element of `@rows`, the single value contained in that row.

Comment: HI I am not sure whether I can continue in the same post, But its for the same script but a different problem. How do I select a clob field and be able print them(not a CGI script) on screen? Sorry, all the examples I found are for a image. And my clob field is not a image but a long text message.

Comment: Thanks Sinan! I have got them printed now.